# input in mapping dictionary python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to implement dict in python.

This code work perfectly:

```
  def numbers_to_strings(argument):
    switcher = {
        0: "zero",
        1: "one",
        2: "two",
    }
    return switcher.get(argument, "nothing")

print (numbers_to_strings(0))
```

In this case the output is "zero".

But when I try to implement the one by input , I always get "nothing" :

```
def numbers_to_strings(argument):
    switcher = {
        0: "zero",
        1: "one",
        2: "two",
    }
    return switcher.get(argument, "nothing")

print ("To write a number: ")
number = input ()
print (numbers_to_strings(number))
```

Best Regards.

Comment: `input` returns strings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Comment: Version of python matters. input works differently in 2.x vs 3.x: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x

Comment: ty man. god bless you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The input is saving the number you enter as string. You need to parse `number` to integer before you call `numbers_to_strings`

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by Daniel Roseman, `input` returns a string so simply change this line:

```
number = input ()
```

to:
    number = int(input())